# Creating a Backup Dataframe from Entries Discarded by Pandas drop_duplicates()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe, ds. And I would like to drop duplicate entries from a particular column, named 'Name'.

```
+---------+------+-------+----------+--------+
| Invoice | Name | Price |   Date   | Coupon |
+---------+------+-------+----------+--------+
|  123412 | Jim  |    50 | 12/01/17 | ALBB1  |
|  431311 | Jane |    25 | 12/02/17 | BB2    |
|  134123 | Joe  |    70 | 12/03/17 | BB2    |
|  333131 | Jim  |    85 | 12/04/17 | ALBB1  |
+---------+------+-------+----------+--------+
```

Here is my code:

```
ds = ds.drop_duplicates(subset='Name', keep='first')
```

I am using the `keep='first'` option to keep the first instance found in the dataframe.

What I would like to do is to create a separate dataframe from all the discarded entries.

So, in this example. The second dataframe, ds2, would be equal to:

```
+---------+------+-------+----------+--------+
| Invoice | Name | Price |   Date   | Coupon |
+---------+------+-------+----------+--------+
|  333131 | Jim  |    85 | 01/04/18 | ALBB1  |
+---------+------+-------+----------+--------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for boolean mask and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

*Notice: `keep='first'` should be omit, because default value*

```
df1 = df[df.duplicated(subset='Name')]
print (df1)
   Invoice Name  Price      Date Coupon
3   333131  Jim     85  12/04/17  ALBB1
```

This boolean mask is possible use for generate both `DataFrame`s, `~` is for inverting boolean mask:

```
m = df.duplicated(subset='Name')
df1 = df[m]
print (df1)
   Invoice Name  Price      Date Coupon
3   333131  Jim     85  12/04/17  ALBB1

df1 = df[~m]
print (df1)

   Invoice  Name  Price      Date Coupon
0   123412   Jim     50  12/01/17  ALBB1
1   431311  Jane     25  12/02/17    BB2
2   134123   Joe     70  12/03/17    BB2
```

Detail:

```
print (m)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool

print (~m)

0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

EDIT:

There is also possible use `keep='last'` for extract all dupes without last one or `keep=False` for extract all dupe values:

```
print (df)
   Invoice  Name  Price      Date Coupon
0   123412   Jim     50  12/01/17  ALBB1
1   431311  Jane     25  12/02/17    BB2
2   134123   Joe     70  12/03/17    BB2
3   333131   Jim     85  12/04/17  ALBB1
4   333131   Jim     86  12/04/17  ALBB2 <- added new dupe row

m = df.duplicated(subset='Name')
df11 = df[m]
print (df11)
   Invoice Name  Price      Date Coupon
3   333131  Jim     85  12/04/17  ALBB1
4   333131  Jim     86  12/04/17  ALBB2

m = df.duplicated(subset='Name', keep='last')
df12 = df[m]
print (df12)
   Invoice Name  Price      Date Coupon
0   123412  Jim     50  12/01/17  ALBB1
3   333131  Jim     85  12/04/17  ALBB1

m = df.duplicated(subset='Name', keep=False)
df13 = df[m]
print (df13)
  Invoice Name  Price      Date Coupon
0   123412  Jim     50  12/01/17  ALBB1
3   333131  Jim     85  12/04/17  ALBB1
4   333131  Jim     86  12/04/17  ALBB2
```

Comment: ha, happy new year : -)

Comment: Welcome back, and happy new year!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Thank you

Comment: Happy new Year for all ;)

Comment: @jezrael What if I wanted to do it on a ```keep=last``` basis?

Comment: I think you need `m = df.duplicated(subset='Name', keep='last')` only

Comment: I add it to answer. Please check it.